# What is this wave function in Chemical bonding?

Tags: bond

Was studying chemical bonding(Valence bond theory) but there came this topic called *wave equation* but  have not studied quantum mechanics,so finding hard to understand these terms.Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

$\Psi$ is the wavefunction describing an electron's motion.  $\Psi^2$ is the probability density function for the electron. $\Psi^2$ is usually interpreted as the probability of finding the electron at a given set of coordinates.

In the case that $\Psi$ is a complex function (in that it contains imaginary numbers and not that it is complicated, which it usually is), $\Psi^2$ is defined as the product of $\Psi$ with its complex conjugate: $\Psi \Psi^*=|\Psi|^2$ so that the probability density function contains only real numbers.

Consider a simple case of $\Psi=a+bi$. The complex conjugate would be $\Psi^*=a-bi$.

$$\Psi \Psi^* = (a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2$$

Often the probability density function is *normalized* so that its integral over all space is 1 (i.e. there is 100% chance of finding the electron in all of space). In the equation below, $A$ is the normalization constant.

$$1=A \int_o^{2\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_o^\infty \Psi \Psi^* dr d\theta \phi$$

Comment: The probability density is given as $\vert\Psi\vert^2$, i.e. the modulus squared.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Surely you meant absolute squared, not modulus?

Comment: @tschoppi Taking into account that $\Psi$ may be *complex*, I thought that *modulus* is the correct term. But I might be wrong ;)

Comment: @KlausWarzecha I've confused *modulus* with *modulo*. Learned something again, what a great day today is :)

Answer (score 0):

A theoretical chemist wants to mathematically describe electron density, energy, and directionality in space from first principles, *ab intio*, pure math.  One can completely ignore atoms and do it with orthogonal polynomials and spherical harmonics.  This proves to be unworkable for needing unending curve fitting (like epicycles for solar system orbits before Copernicus; or SUSY, or dark matter) for things like hybridization, molecular orbitals, and solid state band structure.

One instead derives the math specifically from atomic, molecular, and sold state systems beginning with the Shroedinger equation via Hamiltonian or Lagrangian approaches, as quantum mechanics and its wavefunctions, thus wave equations.  At atomic and molecular scales, electrons being low mass and low energy, the de Broglie equation says there are no little pellets.

If you are doing organic, you survive and prosper by returning to the 1930s with LCAO (linear combination of atomic orbitals - purely descriptive), plus the Woodward-Hoffmann rules as appropriate. LCAO is an empirical black box.  In goes the problem, crank it, out comes the correct answer.  If you are doing pharma, crude LCAO lock-and-key rapidly gives way to detailed calculations for the very many subtle ways electron densities interact.  Pharma requires fit *plus* selectivity.